# Create Trigger Before Deleting A Row with Condition Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, triggers, plpgsql, delete-row

So for example I have this table

```
CREATE TABLE public."table" (
    c1 int4 NOT NULL,
    c2 int4 NOT NULL,
    c3 int4 NOT NULL,
    d varchar(20) NULL,
    e varchar(20) NULL,
    f date NULL
        
    CONSTRAINT table_pkey PRIMARY KEY (c1, c2, c3)
);
```

I want to add a restriction the delete only is possible when c1 and c2 and c3 are specified in other case don't allow the delete

I mean

```
delete from public."table" where c1=X
```

throws ERROR!

```
delete from public."table" where c2=Y
```

throws ERROR!

```
delete from public."table" where c3=Z
```

throws ERROR!

```
delete from public."table" where c1=X and c2=Y
```

throws ERROR!

```
delete from public."table" where c1=X and c3=Z
```

throws ERROR!

and so on

only the delete is posible when

```
delete from public."table" where c1=X and c2=Y and c3=Z
```

X,Y, Z are random values

I try

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION verify_delete()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN

    IF OLD.c1 IS NULL OR OLD.c2 IS NULL OR OLD.c3 IS NULL THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'ERROR!';
    END IF;


    RETURN OLD;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_verify_delete
BEFORE DELETE ON "table"
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE procedure verify_delete();
```

with no luck

any suggestions or ideas?

Comment: A trigger doesn’t validate your query, the delete statement. You could try to do this in a RULE, check the manual for details

Comment: I believe you are thinking that in the statement `delete from public."table" where c1=X and c3=Z ` the lack of `c2` means it is set to `NULL`. That is not the case the `OLD.*` values you are testing are the existing values for that row. So you can do `delete from public."table" where c1=X and c3=Z ` and `c2` could have a non-NULL value and your test would fail.

Comment: @FrankHeikens rule doesn't work either 

CREATE OR REPLACE RULE verify_delete_rule AS
    ON DELETE TO "table"
    WHERE OLD.c1 IS NULL OR OLD.c2 IS NULL OR OLD.c3 IS NULL
    DO INSTEAD
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'Error';

Comment: @AdrianKlaver that is correct, that is the main reason I ask here for help

Comment: The trigger function has no knowledge of the conditions you placed on the delete, therefore it will not work for this purpose. You will have to deal with this at the query building level in whatever client is doing that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to implement your requirement. What you should do depends on what your real problem is.

If your problem is that a badly written interactive statement might inadvertently delete too many rows, you could solve the problem with a statement level trigger that throws an error if the transition table contains too many rows.

Comment: So is impossible to validate some way when the user wants to delete a row it needs to contain the 3 primary keys?

Comment: Exactly. You'd have to change the PostgreSQL server source code.